# Infix compositional operator respecting currying, can one be made in R?

Tags: r, f#, functional-programming

I'm an R beginner, coming in with a couple of years of functional programming (F#) experience. I was wondering if it is possible to have a function composition operator that works like the one in F#.

First of all, I noticed that the dplyr package's composition operator does respect currying - at least when it comes to functions in the package. I was trying to replicate this behavior, and came up with a currying function that seemingly works every time (and is much simpler than any example I saw so far, though it has to be applied one argument at a time) -

```
curry <- function(f, x) {
  function(...) {
    f(x, ...)
  }
}
```

The problem is that a seemingly natural analogue to this defining a pipe forward operator does not seem to work.

```
`%|>%` <- function(f, g) {
  function(x, ...) { g(f(x), ...) }
  }
```

It will return something when functions are composed without giving it any further arguments, but, say, (f %|>% g(2))(2) (where f takes one argument, and g two) will inevitably result in its complaining about the second argument in **g** being unbound. It seems that it does some kind of lazy evaluation (hence no errors when no arguments are supplied), but when called with arguments, it evaluates the "stack" of functions in the wrong order (instead of computing f(2) and plugging into g(2, ...), it tries to call g(2) first).

Note that the below works just fine for single-argument functions. But pipe-forward isn't very useful without currying.

```
`%|>%` <- function(f, g) {
      function(x) { g(f(x)) }
      }
```

I am thankful in advance for some insights into the workings of R, not just directions to the nearest package repository. Yes, I know there is a functional package, but I want to understand how the R interpreter works.

Comment: check and see if `?force` helps?